# ORA-01219 Database not open

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I uninstalled my Oracle then re-installed it without uninstalling my SQL DEVELOPER, on accessing the sqlplus command prompt window and enter any command it gives error ORA-01219, Am using windows 7 pro please help me tackle this issue,

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter database open;
```

You can also use the Windows Service administrator panel to restart the service. Look for service named "OracleService" where  may be something like ORA1. Or from the command line:

```
C:\> sc stop OracleServiceORA1
C:\> sc start OracleServiceORA1
```

As far as SQL Developer, it is simply a Java application and should have no bearing on Oracle database starting correctly.